# Excel: return the number of cells that are not blank

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to find a function that will return the number of cells within a given range that have a number in them.  I want to count the number of responses that people gave, irregardless of the value they entered in the cell.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 14):

If you are looking for a number of cells containing *numeric* values, then `COUNT()` function is what you're looking for:

```
=COUNT(A1:D6)
```

If you are looking number of cells with non-blank values (numeric or otherwise), then `COUNTA()` is the right function:

```
=COUNTA(A1:D6)
```

The last formula works only if none of the cells have empty strings as values (i.e. none of the cells in the range have `=""` or something equivalent in them).  If that is the case, then this formula should be used instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E7:G10<>"") * 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LEN function to find the length of the input of a cell, and then test if it's greater than zero or not.

```
=LEN(A1)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use count to count the number of numbers:

```
=COUNT(Your_range)
```

Count will not count the number of cells that do not have a number (but those don't count do they?)